# Relativistic rendering: ray tracing photon paths affected by masses

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, photons, visualization

Given

- an initial photon position $p_{xyz}$ and its direction of travel $d_{xyz}$
- a set of (point) masses, each with a location $m^i_{xyz}$ and mass $m^i_{m}$
- a time step size $d$

how can I calculate the position and direction of the photon in the next time step as it is influenced by the gravitational wells of the masses?

I want to use this to visualize how the formation of a black hole looks like.

Comment: See https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2019/5/24/first-image-of-a-black-hole and https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2019/5/24/how-to-understand-the-image-of-a-black-hole

Comment: Are you aware of the work by the Double Negative group? They made the ray tracing software used in the movie Interstellar https://www.dneg.com/black-holes/

Comment: You labeled this special relativity, but unless you meant for it to be general relativity (as your question implies) this is reasonably simple.  Within GR, however, this problem is ill-posed as stated.  In order for your positions and directions of travel to be specified, you need to fix the gauge variables. You've implicitly assumed some spatial slicing by saying you're giving "xyz" position, but space and time are combined in GR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard-easy way:

1. Calculate the stress–energy tensor  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for the distribution of mass you chose (assuming that distribution of mass is static - the mass/position/shapes(i.e. the mass density) do not change in time).
2. Introduce this in the Einstein Equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) and solve it for the components of the metric.
3. With the components of the metric, you can calculate the geodesics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) and null paths. The path follow by light is a **null geodesic**. This will result in some non-linear differential equation that you might solve numerically, using the initial conditions.

The hard-hard way is almost the same, but now you also update the positions of the masses, as they orbit each other.

There might be some easy way to do this (e.g you might be able to directly calculate the components of the metric from the stress-energy tensor, for some simple mass distributions), but I am not aware of any.

Moreover, there is also the problem of the coordinate system you use. In some, the equations are easier to solve than in others. You might want to use that to simplify your life or allow for analytical simplifications.

You may also want to use more than just the mass, the angular momentum of the masses also changes the trajectories of the light rays in interesting ways.

Comment: >assuming that distribution of mass is static | For a given photon, the rest of the world is static, right?

Comment: When you say that for a given photon, the rest of the world is static, I am assuming that you are putting yourself in the reference frame of the photon, which cannot be done (argument: if you move to the reference frame of the photon, the photon is at rest, however special relativity requires that the speed of the photon is the same in all reference frames, which in this case is $c$).
A photon leaving the Sun in the direction of the Earth, will not hit the Earth, as it moved out of the way while the photon was traveling (and its mass is not big enough to curve the photon in a meaningful way).